# In Singular value decomposition is there any way to relate singular values to the columns of the original matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, singular-values

Given a Matrix $A$ where the SVD would be 
$$A= U \Sigma V^t$$

Where $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix with its singular values

Assuming that I only had the $\Sigma$ values and I don't have the $U$ and $V$ values. Let's say $\sigma_i$ corresponds to the columns of the $\Sigma$ matrix of singular values.

Is it possible to know which column in the original matrix $A$ does the $\sigma_i$ correspond to? If so how can I do it?